# How to prove this statement in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that $((A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C)) \iff (C \subset A)$

While proving, I was trying to use distributions and intersect both sides of the left equation set $\bar{B}$. It works for $\Rightarrow$, but not sure for $\Leftarrow$

It would be good to get at least 1 hint if my mind is wrong. Thanks in advice

Comment: Hint: distribute on the RHS of the equality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Assume $((A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C))$ holds and let $x \in C$. Then $x \in (A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C)$ thus $x\in A$.
2. If $C \subset A$, then $A\cap C=C$ so
   $$
   A \cap (B \cup C)= (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cup C = 
   $$

Answer (score 1):

„$\Rightarrow$”
$((A\cap B)\cup C)=(A\cup C)\cap (B\cup C)$
$A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C$. Therefore $A\cup C=A$, and we get C is in A.
„$\Leftarrow$”. If $C$ is in $A$, then $((A\cap B)\cup C)=(A\cup C)\cap (B\cup C)=A\cap(B\cup C)$, and all done.

Answer (score 1):

$ \Leftarrow $ is even easier.  Show that if $ x \in LHS $ then $ x \in RHS $ and vice versa.  Using the fact that $ C \subset A $, there aren't many cases to consider.